# Decode & analyze video stream in spring-boot application

Tags: java, spring, opencv, video-streaming

I have an IP camera with video stream in H.264 via rtsp. I want to frame this video stream and analyze the image using OpenCV in the spring-boot application (which will be launched in the docker container), and then relay this video stream to the browser, for example, through WebRTC.

```
                              +-------------------------------+
                              |                               |
+----------------+            | Spring-boot application       |
|                |            |         (java)                |
|   IP-CAM       |            |                               |
|   in H.264     | +------->  +----------+---------+----------+
|   on rtsp://   |            |          |         |          |
|                |            |  H.264   |OpenCV   |  WebRTC  |
+----------------+            | decoder  |analysis |          |
                              +--------------------+----------+
```

I ask for hints with the software stack of my application. I do not want to separate the decoding and analysis logic into different software components (for example, decode using ffmpeg) and I want to have maximum freedom from the system environment (ideally, the entire application should be in the same docker container). I'm just starting to work with video streams in java, for this I ask for help in choosing libraries and ready-made solutions.

Comment: I also have the same issue. Kindly share if did you get any idea regarding this. Thanks.